# UpCasting DownCasting vs HighLevel modules/LowLevel modules

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I am confused with wording used to describe UpCasting/DownCasting compared to wording used to describe level of modules.

Imagine two classes:

```
public class Human
{
}

public class Doctor : Human
{
}
```

If we talk about level of modules, Human class is low level module, while Doctor is high level one. Its how I understand if from some of the posts about high-level and low-level modules (please check comments).

But if we would like to cast Human to Doctor, it would be downcasting. And if we would like to cast Doctor to Human it would be upcasting.

Those namings seems to be oposite. Am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: *"If we talk about level of modules, Human class is low level module, while Doctor is high level one"* - could you please add any references for using the terms low and high that way? I would usually use them the other way round.

Comment: [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195252/dependency-inversion-principle-how-to-define-high-level-policy-and-low-level] Its said there: "The high-level policy never has to dictate any part of that implementation detail. Just plug something in and it goes." For me this fits better for deriving class 'Doctor', where we don't know how 'Human' works. Now I am struggling to find good article that would describe what is high and what is low level.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558256/what-is-high-level-modules-and-low-level-modules] this one says: "High level module is the interface / abstraction that will be consumed directly by the presentation layer. Low level on the other hand are bunch of small modules (subsystems) help the high level do their work." For me closer to presentation layer would be Doctor

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780388/what-are-high-level-modules-and-low-level-modules-in-the-context-of-depende?rq=1] It says: "In laymen's terms: high level modules depend on low level modules(...)". That one also points that Doctor would be High level module.

Comment: Clarification belong into the question, please use the "edit" button accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of [those links](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/435501/upcasting-downcasting-vs-highlevel-modules-lowlevel-modules#comment955809_435501) indicate that Doctor is higher than Human. But that can only be understood if you buy into our arbitrary higher/lower metaphor.

By higher we mean more general, more vague, more abstract. By lower we mean more specific, more exact, more realized.

For example, we know what a Doctor does for a living. We know they went to school. We know they have medical knowledge. (you PHDs just hush for a moment). If we only know we're talking about a Human we don't know those things. They might be true. They might not.

That isn't to say we know nothing if we know they're a human. We know they're a mammal. We know they're a carbon based lifeform. We know they spend much of their lives in traffic.

The metaphor comes from the way some details fade away as we rise high above them in altitude. When so high that people look like ants it's hard to count how many fingers they're holding up. (Usually one or two in this situation since people don't like being looked down on).

At this height it's hard to tell if the human is wearing a lab coat and stethoscope or not. But we can still tell we're looking at a human.  So being a Doctor is a low level detail when compared to being a Human.  Go a little higher though and the humans and the cows will start to look the same. Even the cow doctors.

As for casting, that's deciding how to think of whatever we're casting. When casting takes us away from the low level details we call it an upcast because we're going to look at it from a higher altitude. When it gives low level details it's a downcast because we're going to look at it from a lower altitude.

So far I've based this argument completely on the semantics of the class names: `Human` & `Doctor`. But there is also a structural argument to be made here because your code has `Doctor` inheriting from `Human`. I like it when semantics agree with structure. It's easy on the brain. And here they do. When a class inherits from another it's promising that it has all the details of the one it inherited from. Which makes sense, doctors don't stop being human just because you look at them closely. (Though they might ask you to step back and put your mask on).

That promise is enforced by the compiler and lets us think about this person differently in different contexts where we might and might not care that they are a doctor. That ability to not care when it doesn't matter can wonderfully simplify our code.

But it can certainly confuse humans who think of doctors as way up there.

Comment: Just wanted to say, your "I like it when semantics agree with structure" made me think of dependency inversion as of a way to make structure agree with the desired semantics. E.g. for the author(s) of a 3rd party library, *your* code is the low-level detail (high/low designation being contextual); by using dependency inversion + wrappers/adapters, you introduce structure more aligned to your high-level thinking w/ resp. to your problem domain.

Comment: Obviously, it should not be confused with "higher level abstractions/modules" vs. "lower-level abstractions/modules" categorization based on "code in higher level modules *depends* on code from lower level modules". Something like "int" or "string" or "has set" would be from "lower level" and "Person" would be from "higher level"... which makes module with "Doctor" to be a higher-level module than the one with "Human"... or the same level as both equally used lower-level modules and are used by similar set of higher-level modules (like "PersonHandlingAlgorithms"). (37% serious comment...)

Answer (score 1):

Upcasting vs downcasting refers to going up or down within a type hierarchy. If you imagine a hierarchy as a tree, with the most abstract types (base classes) at the top, and the most concrete classes (derived classes) at the bottom, then casting to a base class amounts to going "up" the tree, while casting to a subclass is like going "down" the tree.

Higher level vs lower level is a bit different - it's not about hierarchy of types, it's more about the concepts themselves. It's a bit hard to explain.

Forget about the Human/Doctor hierarchy for now. Things that are high level generally pertain to concepts that are directly related to the problem domain or purpose of your application - to the thing that people will use it for (e.g. code that determines the overall logic and steps in some business workflow). Higher-level modules are thus more important. Things that are low level are related to the more generic technical details (e.g. a general-purpose library that lets you read files, or a library that manages reading configuration from several sources of different priority).

Now, suppose a step in the high-level business workflow involves reading something like an Excel document, and then doing something with the data. This code would invoke a generic (low-level) module for reading Excel files. In this sense, the high-level module depends on the low-level library in order to actually do the work. And if you just include/import the low-level library into the high-level module, and call it directly, it's a direct compile-time dependency.

However, this binds you to that specific low level library, and you don't necessarily want that. There's a technique called *dependency inversion* that lets you reshuffle the structure of your code and make some use of polymorphism (like inheritance) to invert that dependency, and have the low-level module depend on the high-level module. This lets you (with some amount of planing) reuse the same high-level code with a different low-level library, e.g. one that can read from a different type of file. Dependency inversion is one of the SOLID principles.

But its not just about domain-specific code vs general-purpose code. High-level vs low-level is relative. So, even within your domain-specific code, you can have higher-level parts that capture overall policies, and parts that are lower-level relative to that; these would represent the more variable details.

Maybe a code example can help shed some light, so consider this:

```csharp
public abstract class DataProcessor
{
  // Note that this method defines the high-level policy, which is:
  // * read input file
  // * calculate averages based on the input, unless the input includes them
  // * use the averages (computed or included) to update the internal representation
  public void ProcessData() 
  {
    InputData input = this.ReadInputFile();

    Averages averages = input.Averages;
    if (averages == null) 
    {
        averages = this.CalculateAverages(input);
    }

    this.UpdateInternalRepresentation(averages);
  }

  // None of the methods are implemented here, as the application must 
  // support different implementations for this same overall process
  protected abstract InputData ReadInputFile();
  protected abstract Averages CalculateAverages(InputData input);
  protected abstract void UpdateInternalRepresentation(Averages averages);
}

/* 
 * The derived classes below are all lower-level modules,  
 * in relation to the base the class above; they implement 
 * the details that vary within the overall process
 */

public class JsonDataProcessor : DataProcessor 
{
   // implements the three abstract methods
}

public class BinaryDataProcessor : DataProcessor 
{
   // implements the three abstract methods
}
```

Note that in the high-level module, you can almost read the bullet points off of the code. The `DataProcessor` class quite literally tells you what the overall business process is (as understood by the users), while the derived classes provide specific functionality within that. The developer would then pick one of the derived (concrete) classes based on some criteria, and pass it to some other code as the abstract `DataProcessor`. The calling code would do all of its work through the public interface of `DataProcessor`, which in this example is just the `ProcessData()` method - but in general, there could be other methods there, they could take parameters, etc.

So, if your `Human` class encodes such a high-level policy, and is meant to be used by the calling code in a similar polymorphic fashion, then `Human` is a higher-level module compared to `Doctor`. The code in `Human` is then conceptually *more important* than the code in `Doctor`; the code in `Human` tells you what the application is actually doing for the user, in terms of user's business needs.

However, if `Human` just houses some generic human-related functionality shared by all of its derived classes, and you're just using it to include that functionality in your `Doctor` class, and there's no intent for `Human` to capture some kind of logic that's more important to your application (in the above sense) than whatever the `Doctor` class is providing, than it is not a higher-level module (and, depending on what kind of methods you put in there, it might even be a comparatively lower-level one).

Answer (score 1):

Classes are not actual things; they are abstractions that represent possible ways of looking at things. For example, in this code, we choose to look at a `Doctor` as a `Human`. That does not change the nature of the object itself.

```
Doctor x = new Doctor(); 
Human y = x; //It's the same object, just a different way of looking at it
```

So we are talking about **abstractions**.

A **higher level abstraction** is one that is **more generalizable**, i.e. can apply to more things. There are more `Human`s than there are `Doctor`s, so `Human` is more general, and therefore more abstract, and therefore higher level.

Another way to think of it: If you are flying very high, you might be able to tell there are humans on the ground, but unable to tell they are doctors. Once you fly very low you can tell them apart.